# Searching a list of keywords from text files in folders

Tags: windows, search, text

I have compiled a list of db object names, one name per line, in a text file. I want to know for each names, where it is being used. The target search is a group of folders containing sub-folders of source codes.

Before I give up looking for a tool to do this and start creating my own, perhaps you can help to point to me an existing one.

Ideally, it should be a Windows desktop application. I have not used grep before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `grep` (there are tons of port of this command to windows, search the web).

eventually, use [`AgentRansack`](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home).

Comment: Like most tools I just downloaded from the Net, I have difficulty finding the way to let AgentRansack know my text file which contains the list of keywords to search.

Comment: @IrawanSoetomo: using grep in a command line window: `for /f %v in (keywords.txt) do grep "%v" root\folder\to\search`

Comment: Thanks @Adrien, I just downloaded grep from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm, and when I tried to run grep.exe, it gave me "This application has failed to start because libintl3.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem." I guess I must have missed something.

Comment: @IrawanSoetomo: you have to download the setup program linked at "Complete package, except sources", which contains all the dependencies. any other package do not include the dependencies, which you have to download and install separately (as well as the dependencies of the dependencies, etc.).

Comment: OK, thanks again. I managed to use GREP following your advice. Your DOS for-loop is awesome. But I still need to do it one folder at a time, and have to comb the results carefully too.

Comment: @IrawanSoetomo: list the folders into another file, use another loop: `for /f %f in (folders.txt) do ( for /f %v in (keywords.txt) do grep "%v" %f )`. there are a great number of options for grep which controls the output, try `grep --help` and experiment with the different arguments (have a look at `-l` for a start...)

Comment: While my solution using SSIS package to traverse the folders helped me, your proposed solution will certainly work as well. I am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See our [Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine).  It indexes a large code base according to the atoms (tokens) of the language(s) of interest, and then uses that index to quickly execute structured queries stated in terms of language elememnts.  It is a kind of super-grep, but it isn't fooled by comments or string literals, and it automatically ignores whitespace.  This means you get a lot fewer false positive hits than you get with grep.

If you had an identifier "foo", the following query would find all mentions:

```
 I=foo
```

For C and Java, you can constrain the types of identifier accesses to Use, Read, Write or Defines.

```
  D=bar*
```

would find only *declarations* of identifiers which started with the letters "bar".

You can write more complex queries using sequences of language tokens:

```
'int' I=*baz* '['
```

for C, would find declarations of any variable name that contained the letters "baz" and apparantly declared an array.

You can see the hits in a GUI, and one-click navigate to a source code view of any hit.

It is a Windows application.  It handles a wide variety of languages:  C#, C++, Java, ... and many more.

Comment: Thanks Ira, but what button to load my file containing the list of keywords to search please?

Comment: You can run the tool interactively.   You can also invoke the search machinery in a command line (see the documentation).  If you have your list of identifiers in a file one per line, you can make an .cmd command script with one search  query per line.  The engine will output the hits to the console pretty mumch like grep will do.  As usual "read the docs"

Answer (score 0):

I had created an SSIS package to load my 500+ source code files that is distributed into some depth of folders belongs to several projects, into a table, with 1 row as 1 line from the files (total is 10K+ lines).

I then made a select statement against it, by cross-applying the table that keeps the list of 5K+ keywords of db objects, with the help of RegEx for MS-SQL, http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/. The query took almost 1.5 hr to complete.

I know it's a long winded, but this is exactly what I need. I thank you for your efforts in guiding me. I would be happy to explain the details further, should anyone gets interested using my method.

[image]

```
insert
    dbo.DbObjectUsage
select
    do.Id as DbObjectId,
    fl.Id as FileLineId
from 
    dbo.FileLine as fl -- 10K+
cross apply
    dbo.DbObject as do -- 5K+
where 
    dbo.RegExIsMatch('\b' + do.name + '\b', fl.Line, 0) != 0
```